# Solution must be compiled twice to succeed

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2013, nuget, t4

One of my projects is using Clarius Transformation nuget package to transform a .tt file during build without having to install VS Modeling SDK on each machine. However, in one of the solutions, it seems that it is not transforming the files and generates many errors.

How can I guarantee that this transformation is done?

### UPDATE

I think the problem may be the fact that the nuget packages are not committed to source control. Then visual studio needs to download the package and only after this run the transformation. But this is just a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your specific case, but it sounds like you have a post/pre-build action related to one of the projects which creates the files in a wrong order. Check if one of the custom build options has such actions and make sure it is in the correct position in the build order.

Comment: There aren't manually set build actions. It is so strange that if I unload the project with the Clarius Text Transformation package and load it again, the transformation is done and the build works.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are using the older MSBuild based package restore which restores the NuGet package too late in the process for the custom MSBuild target in the NuGet package to be run.

The MSBuild based package restore, which is enabled when you right click the solution and select Enable NuGet Package Restore, adds a .nuget/NuGet.targets file to your project. If you use the MSBuild based package restore then the NuGet package is restored by MSBuild during the build. However the Clarius.TransformOnBuild NuGet package will be restored too late for MSBuild to be able to use the custom MSBuild Clarius.TransformOnBuild.targets and run the transforms.

If you do not use the MSBuild based package restore, and rely on the newer automatic package restore which is done by Visual Studio itself, then your text template should work. With the newer automatic package restore Visual Studio restores the packages when you start the build but before MSBuild is started. This means that any custom MSBuild targets are properly loaded by MSBuild and will be available for use. The newer automatic package restore was introduced to solve this problem.

From the [NuGet site](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-restore):

> Packages are restored before MSBuild is invoked by Visual Studio. This allows packages that extend MSBuild though targets/props file imports to be restored before MSBuild starts, ensuring a successful build.

Testing this with Visual Studio 2013, with a text template and the Clarius.TransformOnBuild NuGet package installed, the automatic package restore allows the text template to run during the first build. With the MSBuild based package restore the text template is not run the first time but only on the second build after the NuGet packages have been restored.

So your options are:

1. Stop using the MSBuild based package restore.
2. Check your NuGet packages into source control.

Comment: Actually I already removed the nuget.targets and nuget.exe files from my solution and my workspace.  And I also removed the references to nuget.targets from my projects. The only thing that has been kept was the import of clarius.transformonbuild.targets

Comment: The project previously used MSBuild integrated package restore and I followed the steps on Nuget site to migrate to automatic restore. If I create a new project without TFS it works, however the existing one restores the package, but it is not running the Exec task from Clarius.transformonbuild.targets, probably because the value of _TextTransform.Identity is empty (though I don't know what this variable means)